# ASM Direct Call Instruction

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86

1. How can I use the call op code to generate a direct call, without dereferencing a pointer?
2. Since the call instruction can mean any of a number of op codes such as xE8, xFF and x9A, how do I tell Visual Studio which one I want to generate when I use the call instruction?

Comment: An E8-based `call` opcode will only apply to targets with local displacements. Chances are (I don't have MSVC to test with at the moment), then, that your function being called must have local linkage, such as by being declared `static`, at a minimum.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I edited the question to be clearer.

Comment: The choice of jump/branch/call-instruction is commonly done in the linker. Enabling link-time optimizations may make it possible for the linker to use a direct call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembler will figure out which opcode to generate based on what expression you use.

If you write `call foo` it will be a near relative call `E8`. If you write `call [foo]`, `call [eax]` or `call eax` it will be near indirect call `FF` (opcode extension 2). If you write `call foo:bar` (or if the assembler knows you are calling a far procedure) it will be a direct far call `9A`. If you write `call far [foo]` it will be an indirect far call which is also `FF` (but opcode extension 3).

PS: not sure about far call syntax for VS, see the documentation for details. You don't normally use far calls, though.